# Deadlock occur in laptop or mobile

Tags: operating-system, deadlock

I have to give presentation on deadlock In OS and I have so many questions to ask.

If deadlock occurs in laptop, how I(user) knows?
Deadlock occuring means application freezing?
If deadlock occurs so OS manage it automatically?

One of the reasons of mobile hanging is deadlock?

I tried chatgpt but i want someone who knows everything about deadlock.